# Semaphores: Can you signal before wait?

Tags: signals, semaphore, wait

I am working on a conceptual psuedo-code Semaphore assignment for a class.

I want to know if it is possible to invoke signal() on a semaphore before some process has invoked wait() on it. For instance:

```
Shared data:
Semaphore x = 0;

Process 1:
    wait(x);
    print("I'm Process 1, and Process 2 has already printed!");
    terminate();

Process 2:
    print("I'm Process 2!");
    signal(x);
    terminate();
```

The assumption above is that it is not guaranteed which process will be run first, but we want the print statements to execute in the right order (process 2 before process 1). If process 1 starts, it will wait on x. Then process 2 will do its printing, signal x, and allow process 1 to print.

But, if process 2 starts, it will signal x before process 1 has waited on it. The desired outcome would be that x will now be "pre-signaled" for process 1, so that it will skip right over the wait(x) statement. Is this what will actually happen? Or will there be some sort of error because you cannot signal a semaphore that no one is waiting on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definitions for wait() and signal() for a semaphore as follows

```
**wait**(Semaphore S)
{
   while S<=0
     ; //no operation
   S--;
}
**signal**(S)
{
   S++;
}
```

In your code semaphore is initialized with zero (Semaphore x = 0), if you try to wait on it, that process gets blocked as you can see from the definition of wait.That means first process never proceed with out calling signal() from second process.

If second process executes first(signal()), the value of the semaphore gets incremented by 1,so that any process waiting on this can proceed with out waiting.(i.e., Process 2 gets wait() it immediately proceeds)

Comment: I wonder if running into that as a race condition is indicative of a deeper problem and perhaps a semaphore isn't the right solution. I guess it depends on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#release%28%29), you don't have to acquire it. I think it's the job of the programmer to structure their code correctly. In this case, since you don't wait for the semaphore in the second process, it could run out of order.

Comment: Why would I wait for the semaphore in the second process? I want it to run first no matter what.

Comment: Suppose the first process runs first. It will wait for the semaphore, get it, print, and then terminate. Nothing is stopping it from running first.

Comment: It is not the processes that are or are not running first, but the print statements.

What is stopping the first process from printing first is the wait(x) statement.

Suppose the first process runs first. It will begin, then stop at the wait(x) line. It will not proceed past this point. It is not until the second process begins and calls the signal(x) line that process1 will proceed. My question is about what will happen if the second process begins first, and calls signal(x) before the first process has called wait(x).